# Converting PHP to django in stages

Tags: php, python, django, python-3.x

I have a PHP app that I want to convert to django. But I want to do it stages. All the heavy lifting is in the PHP code, so first, I want to just use templates and views to generate the HTML, but still call the PHP code. Then later convert the PHP to python. My issue is that the PHP code expects to get all it's input from the REQUEST object and I've consumed that in the view. Is there any way I can somehow supply that to the PHP code?

Is there some way python can communicate like curl ... it needs to send the request string in the body of a POST request to the URL that will route to the PHP script and get the output back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply read the output with `urllib2` (or one of the many other libraries) and return the response.

```
import urllib2
from django import http

def some_django_view(request):
    fh = urllib2.urlopen('http://your_php_page/?' + request.GET.urlencode())
    return http.HttpResponse(fh.read())
```

Comment: That sounds very simple. I'll try it and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: @LarryMartell : what was your experience . Do you have feedback ?